# Can I send a report from a smart group?

Tags: smartgroups

On Drupal 7 / CiviCRM 5.36.1 I have a smart group that I export with a special mapping mixing data coming from relationships for each contact.

I can use the url : https://domain.net/civicrm/group/search?force=1&context=smog&gid=20&component_mode=1 to access the results and export them but there is no action to send a kind of report.

I would like to get an email once per day with a .csv file.

Is this possible? How would you do this?

Comment: Can you make a report based off a Contact Report and filter it to just your Smart Group?

Comment: thanks Peter for considering my question. I can sure identify the contacts with this method and the next question is how to send a report with a specific mapping? When exporting, I just receive a file with one column for the contact name.

Comment: not sure i follow what you are doing. but you can easily add fields to a Report. https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/reporting/set-up/

Comment: maybe I'm wrong but it seems that I can't use relationships like I can in the export mapping tool. this is what I intend to do.

Comment: generally i avoid civireports and just use Drupal Views and csv if i am using Drupal for the cms

Comment: ok Pete, probably I can't get what I want this way. At least I know it's not adapted this way.